# Is there a way how to pass array of entities into stored procedure?

Tags: hibernate, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

I have a project, which uses hibernate and do need to pass array of entities into stored procedure.

There are tutorials/documentation about stored procedures, procedures using arrays, simple/custom data types. I can find those. But I didn't find *a single* answer/blog post/example/whatever how to pass N entities into stored procedure. All I can find are dozens of unanswered questions, close jira tickets, etc.

Is it somehow possible? I guess the route for it could be: create custom type in oracle(or other db), create stored procedure taking that custom type, then somehow mapping whole entity to that custom type(never did that), and then somehow call that stored procedure with that custom type from springdata (never did that). Should/could work, but the lack of evidence anyone doing that is frightening.

Can someone confirm that outlined path will work, or even better, can show some example/documentation showing that done?

NOTE: Please, I'd like to avoid discussing other strategies, how to achieve "the same result" without stored procedures, or similar ideas. Answer: "no, it's not possible with hibernate/jpa" it's completely fine, and would save me (and others) time thinking about this way.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I was able to find out:

calling stored procedure using db driver is trivial. Doing the same through springdata indirection is nasty, but doable. Calling stored procedure with custom type from hibernate/jpa is not possible as far as I was able to find.

- there is no shown way in documentation how to call stored procedure with custom type, only trivialities are shown.
- there is not way how to implement UserType, Type, SqlType and apply it to stored procedure
- I did not find a way, how to short-circuit hibernate to be able to cram into it plain jdbc call doing this.

Instead I was able to find numerous threads asking for this, where many users weren't able to provide example, including answers from hibernate team on hibernate forum.

I'm not sure if this is valid answer, but empirically I'd say: NO, this is not supported in hibernate. Which is dreadful, since this might become necessary/optimal, and after years of development you are locked in. This inability / exceptional complexity to do trivial task should be indication to use different framework.

If you are in this mess, I think the only possible way out is: flush  if needed, and call stored proc using spring org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure. Sadly this is probably the only way out.